# загрузка и выгрузка файлов из MySql

Tags: php, mysql, файлы

Каким способом лучше загружать в MySql и выгружать из базы различные файлы. К примеру в базе в некой таблице есть одна ячейка с id, другая с постом, третья со списком файлов, которые принадлежат этому посту. И может ли в одной ячейке находиться несколько ссылок на несколько файлов или только на 1? Если будет пример то только +. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Для сохранения списка файлов нужно использовать отдельную таблицу, которая будет связана с `id`. А несколько файлов в одной ячейке не сохраняется, разве что как то закодировать, но это просто по тому, что нас учили в универе не верно.

Так что будет у тебя таблица с пользователем и таблица с ссылками к файлам, которые он залил + сохраняй `id` поста, в котором он их залил(если нужно) что бы можно было инициализировать список в едином экземпляре.

```
CREATE TABLE files (
user_id INT, post_id INT, link varchar(35)
);

CREATE TABLE users (id INT,name text, sorname TEXT...);
```

так можно получить список ссылок на файлы

```
SELECT * from files inner join `users` on `id` = `user_id`;
```

Скрипты примерные, используй по своему усмотрению.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте отдельную таблицу для файлов(допустим, `files`), прикрепите к `id` основной таблицы(условно, по `cat_id`).

Тогда файлы будут принадлежать некой таблице, но храниться в отдельной.

В каждой колонке - одно название файла со своим уникальным идентификатором и идентификатором *родителя*(`cat_id`).

Основная таблица будет вида:

```
id | name
1  | Название
```

Таблица файлов:

```
id | cat_id | name
1  | 1      | default.jpg
2  | 1      | default2.jpg
```